# Instant Message Framework example

Tags: objective-c, instant-messaging

Can someone show an example on how to log in to AIM, then send and receive messages using the IMframework?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the IMFramework? I can't find a link to it on Google

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for examples, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of an Objective-C library for AOL instant messenger. It provides a simple Object Oriented approach to instant messaging.  People have used it in the past to develop iOS IM applications, and even added on to it to support things like [Off-The-Record](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/). You can [check it out on github](https://github.com/unixpickle/LibOrange), download the source, and add the source to your application by manually copying them. Once you have the code in your project, you can sign in like this:

```
AIMLogin * login = [[AIMLogin alloc] initWithUsername:username password:password];
[login setDelegate:self];
if (![login beginAuthorization]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to start authenticating.");
    abort();
}
```

After you have logged in and gotten a session, you can do things like set your status message as follows:

```
AIMBuddyStatus * newStatus = [[AIMBuddyStatus alloc] initWithMessage:@"Using LibOrange on Mac!" type:AIMBuddyStatusAvailable timeIdle:0 caps:nil];
[session.statusHandler updateStatus:newStatus];
[newStatus release];
```

You can send messages to buddies like this:

```
AIMBlistBuddy * buddy = [[theSession.session buddyList] buddyWithUsername:buddyName];
[theSession.messageHandler sendMessage:[AIMMessage messageWithBuddy:buddy message:@"<BODY>Hello, world!</BODY>"]];
```

The library supports pretty much every standard feature that AIM users experience on a day to day basis. See my working example in [MyTest.m](https://github.com/unixpickle/LibOrange/blob/master/LibOrange/MyTest.m). Note that it includes things other than the core functionality, such as thread blocking detection, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know Google is using OpenAIM in gTalk. You can find out more at: http://dev.aol.com/aim

GMail: http://www.google.com/support/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61024

Comment: Cool! How would I incorporate this into an obj-c app?

Comment: this app looks like it can only send messages....is there one that can receive as well?

Comment: It should be both. I just noticed they move to git hub: http://github.com/grinich/WIMTouch . Check the resource section.